# Why is it not showing the correct measurement?

Tags: objects, measurement

Newbie here learning Blender.

Could someone point out what i have done wrong? the measurement unit is not showing the correct measurement of the object, the width of the box is suppose to be 180mm but when i click on to show measurement its written there 500mm instead as you can see in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Because the object has some scale in object mode.